# 504 Gateway Time-out issue

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to run a PHP script and it does run for about 60 seconds or so, and then it goes to a page that says there's a 504 Gateway Time-out.

I've been having this issue all day and I've implemented various things I've found around the internet but it still doesn't work. These including editing the fcgid.conf file, editing .htaccess and even logging in to the Plesk panel, and editing the settings in there.

For testing purposes I'm giving it 2G and 600 seconds to run, which should be enough space and time. But it doesn't seem to be working at all.

I've read online that it could be something to do with nginx, and it does say "Nginx" on my error page, but I'm not really clued up on it to be honest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about `fastcgi_read_timeout`?

Comment: That's one of the things that keeps cropping up in threads I am reading, but not really sure where it lives or how to edit it.

Comment: It's a part of nginx configuration

Comment: I'm in nginx.conf now, I can see keepalive_timeout 65; would it be this that's causing it?

Comment: @DroidShare No, `keepalive_timeout`is for HTTP/1.1 client connections.  If you're not seeing `fastcgi_*` parameters, you're either in the wrong file, or they aren't defined (which might be the issue).  Usually in conf.d, there is a separate file for FastCGI configuration.

Comment: `grep -ir fastcgi /etc/nginx`

Comment: There's a http section within nginx.conf. Could I just add `fastcgi_read_timeout` and then the value somewhere in there?

Comment: All sorted. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: 60 seconds also happens to be the default runtime timeout for PHP. That setting is in your php.ini file.